# Baking (pizza) stone and effects on puff pastry

Tags: baking, equipment, puff-pastry

My pizza stone basically "lives" in my oven and I will be baking on it tomorrow.

Also on tomorrow's kitchen agenda: small [palmiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmier), sugared slices of puff pastry.

As the stone will be hot already, I'm wondering:

**What would be the effect of baking the palmiers on the baking stone vs. baking on a classic cookie sheet?**

(Assuming correct temperature settings and use of parchment to avoid burned in sugar in both cases.)

Comment: Seems easy enough to run the experiment with a bit of store bought frozen puff pastry, but I'd expect the baking stone to lead to more puff and a more crisp bottom.

Comment: @Batman I might be running this experiment, yet I was kind of hoping for answers with "kitchen chemistry" or "kitchen physics" explaining *why* result X is to be expected. ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this, and it didn't turn out so well. My oven was just north of 200 degrees celsius, I didn't want to deal with having the hot stone out of the oven, so I just tossed some sausage rolls on the stone to bake.

By the time the top puffed and browned sufficiently, the bottom was, well, pretty burned. Now, these sausages were pretty big bangers (wrapped in puff pastry), and there was more than a bit of pastry that had to cook, so you might not run into the same issue.

I also didn't experiment further or try again; I just ate my burned rolls and sulked for a while. I have a feeling that if the oven was down in the 180 - 185 range, it probably would have come out quite nicely with a little extra crispness on the bottom.

I'd test one first, just to be on the safe side. Actually it's probably worth making two extra just in case you have to adjust the temperature again. You also might want to use a bit of foil (or parchment as you said), as you'll have some butter on your stone if you don't (and possibly a brown butter taste to it).